# Examining contents of TestContainers

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, liquibase, testcontainers

I am using a PostgreSQL TestContainer to test Liquibase schema migration in Spring Boot. I don't have any respositories. I am wondering if I can see/access the contents of the TestContainer, and test the schema migration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can access the Docker container spawned by Testcontainers like any other Docker container. Using the JUnit 5 extension or the JUnit 4 rule for Testcontainers will however shut down the container after your tests.

You can use the [coontainer re-usability feature](https://rieckpil.de/reuse-containers-with-testcontainers-for-fast-integration-tests/) for Testcontainers (in alpha state since 1.12.3) for ensuring your containers are up- and running after your tests finish.

As Testcontainers will launch the container on an ephemeral port, simply execute `docker ps` and check to which local port the container port is mapped. E.g.:

```
b0df4733babb        postgres:9.6.12      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds       0.0.0.0:32778->5432/tcp   inspiring_dewdney
```

You can now connect to your db on `localhost:32778` with e.g. PgAdmin or the database view of IntelliJ IDEA and check your database tables.

The credentials for the access are those you specify in your test:

```
static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = (PostgreSQLContainer) new PostgreSQLContainer()
  .withDatabaseName("differentDatabaseName")
  .withUsername("duke")
  .withPassword("s3cret")
  .withReuse(true);
```

As a *workaround* you could also put in a breakpoint at the end of your test, debug the test, and quickly check your database.

**UPDATE**: If you want to *verify* the validity of your schema, you can use a Hibernate feature for this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

This will validate that your Java entity setup matches the underlying database schema on application startup. You can also add this to your production `application.properties` file as your application won't start if there is a mismatch (e.g. missing table, column).

For this to work in a test, you need to either use `@DataJpaTest` or use `@SpringBootTest` to the whole application context connect to your local container.

Find more information [here](https://rieckpil.de/howto-best-practices-for-flyway-and-hibernate-with-spring-boot/).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to write explicit junit tests to test the validity of the schema?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a _possible_ solution to validate your schema